# How to make a persistent com server in Python

Tags: python, com

I'd like to create a COM server that can hold it state across the calls. My goal is to have a thread-safe in-memory database. And provide an access to it via COM interface.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Windows-Programming-in-Python-Creating-COM-Servers/

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of popularity of COM I've ended up providing XMLRPC interface at least I know how to diagnose errors if they occur.